# How to create a serial pipe between a windows host and virtual machine in VirtualBox 5.2x version?

Tags: virtualbox, windbg

I am trying to debug the kernel of a windows xp 32-bit pro virtual machine using `windbg` and I am following the steps on the internet.

In the steps,  I should enter the virtualbox settings and enable the serial ports, but when I start up the `winxp` it failed(just like that pic show)...

[image: settings]

failed here:

[image: failed]

I know there is no pipe here

In the tutorial on the internet, the vitualbox has `create pipe` like this

[image: has it]

And my virtualbox version is here:

[image: version]

My question is:

- How can I create a pipe on virtualbox 5.2x version?
- Is this a bugs of virtualbox 5.2x version?
- If there is no bugs, how to configure the virtualbox settings to create pipe?

THX

Jay

Comment: Try unchecking `Connect to existing pipe/socket`. Older versions of VirtualBox had a `Create Pipe` checkbox with the opposite meaning to the newer `Connect to existing`.

Comment: Yes, virtual machine could start up now, but, still not have pipe...

Answer (score 0):

I answered the same question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1057202/how-to-create-a-serial-pipe-between-a-windows-host-and-virtual-machine-in-virtua). You need to uncheck **Connect to existing pipe/socket** and to be sure that **com1** pipe name doesn't exist. Try to check it via [pipelist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pipelist) app.